# Grabing Dojo Original Object given Dom Id

Tags: dojo

I have a DOJO Editor that I add in JS using the method createEditor

```
 require(["dijit/Editor"],
                function(Editor){
                    this.createEditor = function(idToReplace){
                        var myEditorA = new Editor({
                            height: '50px',
                            plugins:['bold','italic']
                        }, document.getElementById(idToReplace));
                        myEditorA.startup();
                    }
                });
```

I need the text inside the Editor after it has been changed.

I hooked up the method getEditorText but it is failing to do as I want it to do.

```
 require(["dijit/Editor"],  "dojo/dom",
    function(Editor, dom){
      this.getEditorText = function(idofEditor){
      //Editor myEditor =Editor(null, dom.byId(idofEditor)); does not work either

                    var myEditor = dom.byId(idofEditor);
                    var content = myEditor.get("value");
            });
```

The value that I need is stored in the attribute "value" in the Editor.

If I store myEditorA in a global variable I can get the content but I need the correct syntax to avoid working with unnecessary global variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dojo widgets (`dijit`) and DOM nodes are treated seperately. For DOM nodes you indeed need to use the `dojo/dom` module and the function `byId()`. For widgets however, you need the `dijit/registry` module and then you can get the widget by its DOM node like this:

```javascript
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/dom"], function(registry, dom) {
    var myEditor = registry.byNode(dom.byId(idofEditor));
});
```

But because the registry also saves your editor with the same ID as your DOM node, you can also access it directly (without using the DOM node) like this:

```javascript
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
    var myEditor = registry.byId(idofEditor);
});
```

I made an example JSFiddle which you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/K7Urq/1/).

Comment: dijit/registry is exactly what I was looking for